# sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I have a text file with a line like this:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED='abae51b1-e1dc-11e8-bfd0-5665b72f6318:1-12559259';
```

Using sed, I would like to remove that line. I have it partially working in that I can match a string of characters (like `GTID_PURGED`) but it won't match the rest of the string until the semicolon (`;`). [This is my regex](https://regex101.com/r/0HsrgR/1):

```
(SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=.*?\;)
```

And this is my full command which produces the error:

```
sed -i 's/(SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=.*?\;)/' test.sql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to remove that line

`s/pattern/replacement/` is the `sed` command to substitute a pattern with a replacement. But you don't give a replacement.
To remove a line, you want `sed -i '/pattern/d'`.

Additional hints:

- unless you use extended regex with `sed`, you have to escape the brackets. For the delete command, the brackets are not useful and you should remove them.
- posix regex doesn't know about the non-greedy modifier (`?`). You might want to use `.*;` or `[^;]*;` instead of `.*?\;`. `;` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: The `(...)` would not be useful with the `d` command, escaped or not, so they should be removed.  Also note that they have been using the regex101 site, which does not know about POSIX regular expressions (the `.*?;` is a PCRE, better written as the POSIX expression `[^;]*;`, if that part of the expression actually has to exist at all).

Comment: true. improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is for substituting a match, and it's missing the replacement string after the last `/` in your example.

If you just want to remove the line, use `d` at the end instead of the `s` at the beginning.

`sed -i '/match/d' filename`